# Solving Sudoku Puzzles using PileExclusion

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, sudoku

I was trying to solve sudoku puzzle. My algorithm uses PileExclusion to remove the possibilities for each node. On certain puzzles am able to get the answer with 1 possible value for each node. On certain others I get one possible answer for most nodes but on certain  nodes i have more than one possible value(which are the right ones) . Are there any other optimizations to further reduce the answer ?or should i make assumptions on certain values ?

Comment: Sounds like a question of efficiency vs complexity, which is more important to you?

Comment: edited now..i wanted to kno if there are any other ways to further reduce my answer ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other techniques for excluding values.  I recently ran into this page:

http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm

32 approaches before you have to resort to trial and error.